# Match returns empty string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am using the following `Regex` to extract data from a string:

```
private static string ExtractRawString(string input, string fieldName)
{
    return Regex.Match(input, $@"{fieldName}:(.+?)\n").Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Where the input string is:

```
NAME OF PRODUCT:         Product 30AMP \n \nCOMPANY PART NUMBER:   11111\nOEM COMPANY:   COMPANY2 \n \nADD IMAGE HERE:    \n \n \n \n - CHECKED \n \n  \nOEM PART NUMBER:  22222 \nSERIAL NUMBER:  33333 \nCLASSIFICATION:   Product \nDIMENSIONS: UNKNOWN \nWEIGHT:  0.06Kg’s \nCOMPANY PRICE (INC VAT):  R 450.53 ZAR \nOEM PRICE:  \nCoO:  USA/MEXICO \n
```

For example, I could call the function like this:

```
var productName = ExtractRawString(inputString, "NAME OF PRODUCT");
```

This works for every field in the input string (e.g. `NAME OF PRODUCT`, `COMPANY PART NUMBER`, etc.) aprt from `COMPANY PRICE (INC VAT)`.

When I call the following, it just returns an empty string (`""`):

```
var companyPrice = ExtractRawString(inputString, "COMPANY PRICE (INC VAT)");
```

I tried replacing `(.+?)` in the `Regex` with `(.)` but with the same result.

Can anyone tell why this returns an empty string, when the format is the same as all the other fields?

Comment: You should be using `Regex.Escape(fieldName)` to escape any regular expression special characters like `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the key name, else, `(` and `)` are treated as *grouping construct* operators. This can be done with `Regex.Escape()` method.

Also, the `:(.+?)\n` part of the pattern requires a newline to be present. You need to just use a *greedy* quantifier version and remove `\n` since `.` matches any char but a newline in .NET regex:

```
$@"{Regex.Escape(fieldName)}:(.+)"
```

Here, `Regex.Escape()` will add literal backslashes in front of any special regex character, so that `(` could match a literal `(`, etc. The greedy quantifier will grab 1 or more non-newline chars at once, while the lazy one (`+?`) made the regex engine skip the quantified pattern and was trying to match a newline, which made the `\n` a required pattern part and made the pattern rather inefficient.

Note that in order to make `.` match any char but a newline, you should not pass the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option to the Regex constructor. If you can't control that, use a modifier group like this to make the `.` match non-newlines:

```
$@"{Regex.Escape(fieldName)}:((?-s:.+))"
                              ^^^^^  ^
```

See an example `COMPANY PRICE \(INC VAT\):((?-s:.+))` regex demo on [an online .NET regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=COMPANY%20PRICE%20%5C%28INC%20VAT%5C%29%3A%28%28%3F-s%3A.%2B%29%29&i=NAME%20OF%20PRODUCT%3A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Product%2030AMP%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0ACOMPANY%20PART%20NUMBER%3A%20%20%2011111%0D%0AOEM%20COMPANY%3A%20%20%20COMPANY2%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0AADD%20IMAGE%20HERE%3A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%EF%82%A8%20-%20CHECKED%20%0D%0A%20%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0AOEM%20PART%20NUMBER%3A%20%2022222%20%0D%0ASERIAL%20NUMBER%3A%20%2033333%20%0D%0ACLASSIFICATION%3A%20%20%20Product%20%0D%0ADIMENSIONS%3A%20UNKNOWN%20%0D%0AWEIGHT%3A%20%200.06Kg%E2%80%99s%20%0D%0ACOMPANY%20PRICE%20%28INC%20VAT%29%3A%20%20R%20450.53%20ZAR%20%0D%0AOEM%20PRICE%3A%20%20%0D%0ACoO%3A%20%20USA%2FMEXICO%20%0D%0A).

Comment: That's not the issue.  They need to escape the field name because of the ( and ) in the name.

Comment: Good, added that detail, too. Still, I believe the pattern should be enhanced.

Comment: This fails as (for example) `productName` now contains everything after the string `PRODUCT NAME:` rather than everything inbetween `PRODUCT NAME:` and the first `\n` thereafter. Every field name + value in the input string is followd by a `\n`

Comment: @Bessie: It is impossible *unless* you pass `RegexOptions.Singleline` option. However, I cannot see this in the code you shared. See the edited answer, I added an expression that just should work regardless of the options you pass.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, my bad - your original solution actually does work, I accidentally left a test case in my code. Thanks!

Comment: @Bassie: Good, I also added a regex demo fiddle to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't parenthesis escaped by triple parenthesis in a string, in C#?  I would look into making sure that's occurring first.

Comment: They need to be escaped by backslashes so the regular expression will not see them as the beginning and end of a capturing group.  I'm not sure what you're talking about.